# CI for Bernoulli parameter

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, confidence-interval

$X_1, ..., X_n \in B(\theta)$. Find CI for $\theta$ with given $\alpha$
We know that $E[B]=\theta, D(X)=\theta(1-\theta)$

$\frac{\bar{X}-E[X]}{\delta/\sqrt{n}} \in N(0,1)=\frac{\bar{X}-\theta}{\theta(1-\theta)}$
CI I've got:
$\bar{X}+-Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{\sqrt{n}}$

But how to get rid of $\theta$ ?

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Comment: Please recall the UYV principle which says $J(X-Z)=\mu^2+1$.